# django's SubfieldBase leaves input as None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to make a field in Django that stores python dictionaries as json.

When I do it like this:

```
class DictionaryField(models.TextField):
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)
```

to_python isn't called when it's retrieved from the database and I end up with just a string.

When I do it like this:

```
class DictionaryField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)
```

to_python is called!  And I end up with a python object as desired.  But if I delete the models already saved in the database and try to recreate them, they end up as None!  Somehow get_db_prep_value stops working and just returns None or something.

What am I doing wrong??

edit:

If I print the inputted 'value' passed to get_db_prep_value, then when

```
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
```

is present, 'value' is just None.  Without it, it's exactly the value I want.

Comment: There are many tested packages that implement a JsonField class, such as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield, why not use one instead of struggling with your own?

Comment: I'd rather not introduce another dependency to the project.  And also django provides a way to make custom fields, so I'd like to be able to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, in case anyone's curious, was to upgrade from Django 1.7 to Django 1.8.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793259/in-a-django-custom-field-what-does-the-subfieldbase-metaclass-do)