# In a django custom field, what does the SubfieldBase metaclass do?

Tags: django, django-models

When you implement a custom Django field, you're supposed to include this line:

```
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
```

in the class definition, as in:

```
class SomeCustomField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
```

What does that actually do?

Update:

This is the source code for the metaclass (from the Django project):

```
class SubfieldBase(type):
    """
    A metaclass for custom Field subclasses. This ensures the model's attribute
    has the descriptor protocol attached to it.
    """
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super(SubfieldBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class.contribute_to_class = make_contrib(
            new_class, attrs.get('contribute_to_class')
        )
        return new_class
```

How does that cause to_python to be called?  And what would be called otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Django versions<=1.7**, Django provides a metaclass called `SubfieldBase`.

**The main feature of `SubFieldBase` is that is calls [`to_python()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) on assignment.** So, when you added a `__metaclass__`, it will automatically call the `to_python()` function to convert the value into the correct Python object. It handles those fields where type conversion is needed when loading from the database but is not used in `.values()` calls or in aggregates.

This has been **changed in Django 1.8** though. It has been replaced with [`from_db_value().`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value)

As per the [Django 1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects):

> Historically, Django provided a metaclass called `SubfieldBase` which
>   always called `to_python()` on assignment. This did not play nicely with
>   custom database transformations, aggregation, or values queries, so it
>   has been replaced with `from_db_value()`.

Comment: Ok so the answer is definitely just: stop using django 1.7 and switch to 1.8!  :) thanks

Comment: Note: If your custom Field class deals with data structures that are more complex than strings, dates, integers, or floats, then you may need to override `from_db_value()` and `to_python()`.

Comment: If, however, you want that check on assignment then in Django 1.8 you'll need to implement it yourself.